# I can not autenticate on web portal using Tor Browser

Tags: authentication

I am trying desperately to login over Tor browser to some web server (`www.azet.sk`) using certificate Ringier Axel Springer Certificate authentication.

Result is always error message such as inserted user credentials are not valid.

Does anybody have idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times logins fail because either:

1. Tor exit nodes are blocked, in which case you can't do anything.
2. JavaScript is disabled but required to login, click the blue S in the toolbar and then click "Temporarily allow all this page". If you can't see that menu entry, it's probably already enabled

Comment: Dear Sir, issues are persiting. Would you be so kind and check at link ? Thanks. Regards http://textuploader.com/dr5js